# Hide a div behind a transparent div with a responsive background image for the whole page

Tags: css

I want to create a "title bar" with only text.

The content in the div below should disappear underneath this "title bar div" when scrolling.
I have a dynamic background image in a separate div on another z-index level.
Is it anyhow possible to make the whole "title bar" transparent for the background, but NOT for the div below it?
OR, can I somehow set the same background to the title bar, thus making it non-transparent (note that the background image is responsive)?
See [here](http://www.ederveen.be/sophia) for an example of what it does now.

CSS:

```
.top_menu { position:fixed; height:100px; margin-left:5%; width:95%; z-index:2; }
.content { position:relative; left:180px; top:100px; z-index:2; }
#background_image { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; background:#D3AA69 url("/img/background.gif") repeat-x; background-size:auto 100%; }
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="top_menu"></div> <!--(the DIV I want to stay on top)-->
<div class="content"></div> <!--(the DIV I want to hide when scrolling)-->
<div id="background_image"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, kingkero, for the improved editing! This is my very first question. So far I've always found other people with the same problem already solved, but this time I needed some more precise help.
Looks much better now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with CSS, unfortunately.
Using a simple JavaScript however, it is fairly easy to set the height of the content DIV:

```
function setContentHeight() {
var ContentHeight = $(window).height();     
ContentHeight = ContentHeight - 100 ;
ContentHeight = ContentHeight + "px" ;
document.getElementById("ContentDIV").style.height = ContentHeight ; }
```